# Update value of the variable in function globally so next map iteration has the updated value in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, functional-programming

I have a simple function where I am updating the global values and these values are being used in map iteration but values does not get updated in map iterations.

index.js

```
 var arrayTest = [Mark, John, Patrick];
 var xTest = 0;
 var yTest = 0;

function testGlobal(xTest, yTest) {
    xTest = xTest + 1;
    yTest = yTest + 1;
    console.log(xTest, yTest);
  }

 arrayTest.map((index) => {
        testGlobal(xTest, yTest);
      });
```

I want testGlobal to be called first with 0 and 0 and then with 1 and 1 and then 2 and 2 and on... Currently with this setup, every map call is with 0.

Comment: Why is this tagged react? If it's irrelevant, the tags should be removed, but if you're updating some global data in React, the answers would be completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're calling your `testGlobal` function only values of your global variables get passed in there, not the reference itself. Therefore, your `xTest` and `yTest` function input parameters have the value of `0` each time. Since these function parameters share the same name with your global variables, your global variables are ignored within the function scope. So, while you might think you're incrementing your global variables, you're actually incrementing only the function input parameters. That's the reason your `console.log` keeps displaying `1 1` after each function call. You have multiple ways to fix this, here are some of them:

**First approach - passing object reference**

```
var arrayTest = ['Mark', 'John', 'Patrick'];
var test = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};

function testGlobal(test) {
  test.x++;
  test.y++;
  console.log(test.x, test.y);
}

arrayTest.map((index) => {
  testGlobal(test);
});
```

**Second approach - change method variable names**

```
var arrayTest = ['Mark', 'John', 'Patrick'];
var xTest = 0;
var yTest = 0;

function testGlobal(x, y) {
  xTest = x + 1;
  yTest = y + 1;
  console.log(xTest, yTest);
}

arrayTest.map((index) => {
  testGlobal(xTest, yTest);
});
```

**Third approach - don't pass anything, increment global variables directly**

```
var arrayTest = ['Mark', 'John', 'Patrick'];
var xTest = 0;
var yTest = 0;

function testGlobal() {
  xTest++;
  yTest++;
  console.log(xTest, yTest);
}

arrayTest.map((index) => {
  testGlobal();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use different name for the testGlobal function arguments like below.

```js
function testGlobal(x, y) {
    xTest = x + 1;
    yTest = y + 1;
    console.log(xTest, yTest);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason in this case is because you changing the values of the function parameters not the variable declarations at the top.

```
   function testGlobal() {
    xTest = xTest + 1;
    yTest = yTest + 1;
    console.log(xTest, yTest);
  }
// xTest = 2
// yTest = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You are shadowing your globals with the parameter labels of your function. Change the parameter names or omit them and it will work.

```
var arrayTest = ["Mark", "John", "Patrick"];
var xTest = 0;
var yTest = 0;

function testGlobal() {
  console.log(xTest, yTest);
  xTest++;
  yTest++;
}

arrayTest.map(() => {
  testGlobal();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like we may need more information to best answer your question. For instance, how are you using React in this scenario? Are you rendering the global variables to the page? Are the global variables even necessary, and if so, why? If both the global variables will be the same then why is there a need to have 2 separate variables that track the same value? Are the variables always starting a 0 and incrementing by 1 for each item in the array? If this last one is true then you should just be able to use the `index` parameter of `map` and do something like this inside your component:

```js
var arrayTest = ["Mark", "John", "Patrick"];

function testGlobal(count) {
    console.log(count);
}

return (
    <div>
        {arrayTest.map((_, index) => {
            testGlobal(index);

            // or render something:
            // <p>{index}</p>

            // or pass count to child component:
            // <Child count={index} />
        })}
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this**

```
var arrayTest = ["Mark", "John", "Patrick"];
 var xTest = 0;
 var yTest = 0;

function testGlobal(xTest, yTest) {
    window.xTest = xTest + 1;
    window.yTest = yTest + 1;
    console.log(xTest, yTest);
  }

 arrayTest.map((index) => {
        testGlobal(xTest, yTest);
      });
```